# How many ways are there to divide 10 customers across 2 salespeople?

Tags: combinations, factorial

An article quotes that "there are more than 1,000 ways to assign ten customers to two salespeople" however this is wrong! How many actual ways are there to divide these customers across the two salespeople and what is the method used to get to this number?

I believe I should use combinations to answer this question but i'm not sure if im right. My thoughts were if the combination formula is nCr = n!/(n−r)!r! then it would be 10c5 = 10!/((10-5)!5! = 252

Thank you for any help you can provide :)

Comment: Take some non-empty subset of the customers and assign it to the first salesmen. There are $2^{10}-1$ ways to make this assignment.

Comment: @Bum, why non-empty? I don't see that required in the problem statement.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: If I was the manager, I don't need one person to do all the work while the other does nothing. But you are right, the problem statement doesn't ask that.

Comment: @Bumblebee But why let the *other* salesman do nothing while not letting the *first* salesman? If you are discounting both of those situations, the answer is $2^{10}-2=1022$.

Comment: "Assigning ten customers to two salespeople" isn't necessarily equivalent to "dividing ten customers between two salespeople".  You could assign a customer to both salespeople.  But the initial statement probably assumes to assign each customer to exactly one salesperson, and not necessarily equally between them.

Answer (score 4):

If each customer can be assigned to either salesperson, the answer is $2^{10}=1024$.  That is clearly what the statement is thinking.  Each customer can be assigned $2$ ways and you use the multiplication principle to combine them.  You are assuming that each salesperson must be responsible for $5$ customers, but that is not stated in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The customers, being humans, are distinct. There is no restriction on splitting the load, so as stated the quote is right; each customer may go to either salesperson independently, and there are $2^{10}=1024$ choices overall.

You assume in deriving your answer of $\binom{10}5=252$ that the load must be distributed evenly and that order doesn't matter.